# Delete a Linked List before closing a C++ program?

Tags: c++

I have a doubt which is as follows...

Linked List deals with pointers and dynamic allocation. So they have provided a keyword `new` which allocates a chunk(that's how it's spelled I suppose) of memory in the *heap* store and returns a pointer pointing to it. And they have also provided the `delete` keyword which frees the memory to which the pointer returned by the new is pointing.

So suppose I've created a Linked List of say 10 *nodes* then should I have to create a function to scan through each node and delete each node? Because in my textbook they have written that if you don't delete a dynamically allocated object then it causes memory leak...

So in short do I have to scan through each node deleting each node before closing a C++ console application??

---

### Aditional Details

**Operating System** Windows 7

**Compiler** Turbo C++

Comment: Before the program closes? Strictly speaking, No. But it is good practice to do so.

Comment: @MitchWheat"  Don't confuse the poor guy.

Comment: @ John Dibling: I'm not. That is 100% correct.

Comment: So you think I am a poor guy, huh??

Comment: @TheDreamCoder17:  I was being facetious.

Answer (score 3):

It is a good practice that for each memory allocated, there is a class or function responsible for freeing it if it won't be used any more.

Still, all the memory used by program will be freed by operating system when the program is closed. But I think that your teacher (homework, isn't it?) or boss would rather you freed the memory.

The bottom line is: `delete` everything you created with `new`.

Answer (score 1):

> So in short do I have to scan through each node deleting each node
>   before closing a C++ console application??

Sure you can `delete` it before closing your problem, if you did not `delete` it, then `operating system` will anyway clear memory consumed by your application / program.

Once, if you know, your `heap` memory is no more useful better to `delete` it (instead of waiting for closing program)

```
{
  Allocation with new...
  call function(using allocated memory)
  ....
  ....
  call function2(using allocated memory)

  not using allocated memory here after..
  **Delete Your heap memory..**

  call AnotherFunction()
  ....
  ...

  Alternatively, you can release / delete memory here also. (Good practice than not deleting :) )
  end of main / application.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't actually *have* to do so.

Nearly all code should, however, be written in a way that the data gets deleted when the object that owns it goes out of scope, so this will happen (almost) unavoidably.

In other words, you should *not* normally have something like:

```
// WARNING: bad code. Avoid this, or anything similar.
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

node *head = NULL;

int main() { 
     node *t = new node;
     t->data = 1;
     t->next = head;
     head = t;

     t = new node;
     t->data = 2;
     t->next = head;
     head = t;

     // here, do we bother to delete the two nodes or not?
};
```

Instead, what you normally want to do is create a class that encapsulates all the work, and in its destructor it frees all the memory it owns:

```
class linked_list {
    struct node { 
        int data;
        node *next;

        node(int data, node *next = NULL) : data(data), next(next) {}    
    } *root;
public:
    void add(int data) {
        root = new node(data, root);
    }

    ~linked_list() { 
       node *prev = root;
       for (node *temp = prev->next; temp!=NULL; temp=temp->next) {
            delete prev;
            prev = temp;
       }
       delete prev;
    }       
};
```

With a class like this, there's really no decision to make:

```
int main() { 
    linked_list x;

    x.add(1);
    x.add(2);
}
```

When execution reaches the end of the block in which `x` was defined, `x` goes out of scope and gets destroyed. In the process, its destructor is invoked, and that deletes the nodes in the linked list (modulo any bugs in my code, of course). There's no need to think or care about whether it makes sense to delete the nodes in this case, because it simply happens automatically every time.

Note that I'm not saying this code is (even close to) 100% ideal either. With a compiler modern enough to support it you'd almost certainly want it to be a template to allow storing an arbitrary type, and use a `unique_ptr` and `make_unique` instead of a raw pointer and raw `new`. Unfortunately, I have little choice but to leave these out, since I'm sure Turbo C++ doesn't support `unique_ptr`, and doubt it supports templates either. For real use, this should also include a copy constructor and assignment operator as well, so assigning and copying linked lists would work correctly (as it stands now, either will typically lead to problems because it'll end up attempting to destroy the nodes in the linked list twice).

Final note: of course, you usually shouldn't write your own linked list code anyway. But when/if you do have a reason to writer a container (or something similar) it should clean up its own mess, so to speak. One of the real strengths of C++ is deterministic destruction; use it.